# CRC-16 (Modbus) calculation---- Not able to pass hexa values to the funtion

Tags: c

Not able to pass hexa values to the funtion
I am trying to  send the hexa decimal values to crc16_2(). it is not showing any errors, but i am not getting the output.
Please got to the last line in the code for output for the data in hexa values in abc[] array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
unsigned int CRC16_2(unsigned int *buf, int len)
{
    unsigned int crc = 0xFFFF;
    for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++)
    {
        crc ^= (unsigned int)buf[pos];  // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc
        for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--)
        {    // Loop over each bit
            if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0)
            {      // If the LSB is set
            crc >>= 1;                  // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
            crc ^= 0xA001;
            }
            else                        // Else LSB is not set
            crc >>= 1;                  // Just shift right
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned int abc[5]={0x020300000001,0x020300010001,0x020300020001,0x020300030001,0x020300040001};
    unsigned int final;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        final=CRC16_2(abc[i],12);
        printf("%.4x\n",final);
    }
}
//outputs are : 3984, F9D5, F925, 3974, F8C5
```

Comment: You should really spend a bit of time formatting you question; not many people will help you with it in its current state.

Comment: Use long long instead of int, 0x020300000001 wont fit in 4 byte int, first confirm int size with sizeof int

Answer (score 0):

As Pras said:

> Use long long instead of int, 0x020300000001 wont fit in 4 byte int,
>   first confirm int size with sizeof int

Also you pass 1 Element of your array to the function so it is just an integer. (that is cut to the last 4 byte).

The function accepts a pointer to an integer but you give it an integer. As far as we know the memory is not allocated for your program so this is undefined behaviour, as soon as you dereference it.

Also you access the integer pionter but you just work on 2 bytes. This seems strange.

So either you dont show us the complete code or you could change your code to something similar like:

> pass the variable
>
> split it into 2 byte parts and save it into an array. Then you can use
>   your double `for` loop to process it.

or

> if you already want to pass the array you have to split it correctly
>   (2 byte chunks) before hand and then pass it correctly

and generally use the data type that can contain the variable you want to save.